# Responsiveness on Four Columns to Two Columns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, floating

I am creating a responsive website with four columns. When the screen gets narrower I would like the four columns to turn into two columns.  However when column two is shorter than column one this approach fails, in that column 3 is below 2 and there is a huge gap before seeing column 4 below column 1.  Is there a way to not have this huge gap using CSS?  I do not want to add an additional HTML element, however if I have to I can.

http://jsfiddle.net/ACJHg/

Comment: you can do this by change the margin according to the screen resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `clear: left` to your third column (using `.fourcolumn:nth-child(3)`) or to odd columns in general (using `.fourcolumn:nth-child(2n+1)`)

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ACJHg/1/)

[Also, it would be better to start with the narrow screen and then go to the wider screen (mobile first approach) and [use `em` based media queries instead of `px` based ones](http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/) (to prevent layout from breaking when the user zooms)]

Comment: Awesome, that's a great little trick! However, I did have to modify it to `.fourcolumn:nth-child(2n+2) { clear: left; }`